# Is there any evidence that honey can help a COVID cough?

Tags: covid-19, cough, traditional-medicine

A cough is a frequent clinical sign of COVID-19, and there is [some indication](https://bmjopenrespres.bmj.com/content/8/1/e001049) that coughing can cause lung "sprain" and long lasting damage.

The UK National Health service has a page on [Self-care and treatments for COVID-19](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/self-care-and-treatments-for-coronavirus/how-to-treat-symptoms-at-home/).  It is a little sparse on curative treatments, with pharmacological interventions limited to paracetamol or ibuprofen to use as an antipyretic (with a comment about the safety of ibuprofen), and a teaspoon of honey to treat a cough.  There is no indication as to if this is used as an antitussive or an expectorant.

Is there any evidence that honey can be curative for a cough, rather than palliative?  Is there any indication of a mechanism?

Comment: When you search Google for "honey cough covid" you can find plenty of information, including scientific papers, such as this one: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213422021000664       Evidence is limited, naturally, but it's there.

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/30649/has-there-been-any-medical-studies-as-to-whether-drinking-a-hot-toddy-can-help/30652#30652

Comment: Honey isn't curative for any cough. There is some evidence that certain honeys have *antibacterial* properties in direct contact, but no evidence for *antiviral* The honey isn't getting to where the cough actually happens (lungs/trachea), it merely soothes the throat, providing some sort of protective layer.

Comment: I think the answer @motosubatsu linked to actually answers this question. The questions aren't _exact_ duplicates, so I'm not voting to close as a duplicate, but I think this question should reference the answer linked to and explain why it doesn't answer it.

Comment: I think the linked answer practically answers the question.  Closing this as a duplicate could be appropriate, but I do not know.